# aws-sdk 403 Error for CORS preflight OPTIONS request to Quicksight API

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors, aws-sdk-js, amazon-quicksight

I'm trying to register a temporary quicksight user and generate an embed url to put in my React App. However, when calling the register user api I get a 403 error for the CORS preflight OPTIONS request:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://quicksight.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/accounts//namespaces/default/users' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

I've also tried using `us-east-1` as my region, but that also fails.

Users sign into my webapp with Cognito credentials. The identity pool has an associated IAM role, and I've attached a policy to that role giving access to register a new quicksight user and get the embed url. My webapp currently uses the aws-sdk library to assume the role through sts, and then make the subsequent quicksight calls.

The React app is hosted on Amplify

```
  quicksightRegisterUser(data) {
    var params = {
                   AwsAccountId: 'QQQ',
                   Email: 'XXX',
                   IdentityType: 'IAM' ,
                   Namespace: 'default',
                   UserRole: "READER",
                   IamArn: 'arn:aws:iam::YYY:role/ZZZ',
                   SessionName: 'XXX',
                   UserName:'XXX'
               };

    var quicksight = new QuickSight();
    quicksight.registerUser(params, function (err, data1) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("err register user");
        console.log(err);
    } // an error occurred
      else {
          console.log("Register User1");
          console.log(data1)
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? Use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error instead of 200 OK success response?

Comment: It's a 403 error on the OPTIONS call

Comment: The `https://quicksight.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/accounts/` endpoint needs to be configured to respond to unauthenticated OPTIONS requests with a 200 OK. Right now it’s responding with 403, which causes the preflight to fail. So the browser stops right there & never even tries your quicksight.registerUser(…) call. So to get more help, you want to use https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56290111/edit to edit/update the question & provide details about your server-code on the `https://quicksight.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/accounts/` server. Without knowing more about that, nobody here can help

Comment: Thanks for your reply - the quicksight API isn't owned or maintained by me however, it's an AWS standard API, so I have no control over the Server CORS policy

Comment: Then it sounds like that API isn’t intended to be called from frontend JavaScript running in a browser. The alternative is to make the calls to it from your backend code instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @sideshowbarker mentioned, you can't call the Quicksight API from your webapp.

The solution I found was to set-up a Lambda to generate the Embedding URL, given the user's Cognito Username and password.

Full details of the solution, and a step-by-step tutorial, can be found here:
https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-quicksight-embedding-sample